# VueX - Dispatch action in a different module from an action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I would like to clear user data upon `logout`, so from `auth` module I `dispatch` an action which is defined in a module `ride` but I am getting an error:

`[vuex] unknown local action type: clearUserData, global type: auth/clearUserData`

This is my code:

#### store/modules/auth.js

```
export const namespaced = true

export const mutations = {
  clearAuthData(state){
    state.apiToken = null
    state.signedIn = false
  }
}

export const actions = {
  logout({ commit, dispatch }) {
    commit('clearAuthData'))
    dispatch('ride/clearUserData', { root: true })

  }
}
```

#### store/modules/ride.js

```
export const namespaced = true

export const state = {
  data: []
}

export const mutations = {
  CLEAR_USER_DATA(state){
    state.data = []
  }
}

export const actions = {  
  clearUserData({ commit }) {
    commit('CLEAR_USER_DATA')
  }
}
```

#### store/store.js

```
import * as auth from './modules/auth'
import * as ride from './modules/ride'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loading: false
  },
  modules: {
    auth,
    ride
  }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried it on my local but I can't reproduce your bug. Can  you create a demo that will reproduce this scenario?

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac Here's a link to a video I recorded https://monosnap.com/direct/QiLE0hBMsWaxBliUAs9P37j8mCOllC

Comment: I am using "vuex": "^3.1.0", if that matters

Comment: I'm using the same version but still can't reproduce the issue. Can you show how you import the `auth` and `ride` modules in the `store.js` file as well.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac Here's my source code of the app in case you need to take a look around https://github.com/jedrekdomanski/bikeramp-front

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your [usage of `dispatch()`](https://github.com/jedrekdomanski/bikeramp-front/blob/c2464ce/src/store/modules/auth.js#L67) is incorrectly passing `{ root: true }` as the *2nd* argument, which is intended for the payload. Options should be 3rd:

```js
// dispatch('ride/clearUserData', { root: true }) // FIXME: options passed as payload
dispatch('ride/clearUserData', null, { root: true })
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have payload to pass, then you need to send the second parameter as a `null` like:

```
dispatch('ride/clearUserData', null, { root: true })
```